# How do I set the default Firefox zoom level for *local* files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, firefox-extensions

Every time I open a new local file, the zoom level is reset to 100%. Is there a way/extension to make the default a different zoom percent?

It'd be even better (but not required) if I could set this per file path. e.g., all `C:/docs` files open at 500%. The rest would be at 100%.

Comment: Asking for extensions is off topic

Comment: @DavidPostill is there a more appropriate site that allows asking for this?

Comment: Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: To me this looks like a well written question at the right place. ["If you have a question about computer software, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Some options:

- Install **Tampermonkey**, this is a Firefox extension to run your own Javascript code on websites of your choice.

  Then you can make a script like this:

  ```js
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name         Zoom Qt docs
  // @match        file:///C:/qt/Docs/*
  // @grant        GM_addStyle
  // ==/UserScript==

  var scale = 1.2;

  var css = `
      html {
          width: ${100 / scale}%;
          transform-origin: top left;
          transform: scale(${scale});
      }
  `;

  GM_addStyle(css);
  ```

  Text rendering seems to be worse when using this instead of normal
  browser zoom (Firefox 108), so I do not recommend this.
- Write a **Firefox extension** to set the browser zoom level, this seems to be possible with the [browser.tabs.setZoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/setZoom) function. I was hoping I could call this function from a  Tampermonkey script, but that seems to be impossible.
- Run a local **web server**. Let it listen on 127.0.0.1 so it doesn't allow connections from other computers. To have different zoom settings for different sites, make up a hostname for every site and add the hostnames to your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). Let them all point to 127.0.0.1.

  I ended up installing NGINX with this configuration:

  ```
  events {}

  http {
      server {
          listen 127.0.0.1:80;
          location / {
              root "c:\\";
              autoindex on;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't have an eye for these things, but I increased the scale in your first solution to 7x and the text didn't look a worse for me. I vaguely recall turning on svg fonts on Windows years ago, so maybe that's relevant?